# Execute my functions Asynchronously in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I am new to NodeJS. I know there are a lot of questions about asynchronous NodeJS but I couldn't find exactly what I am looking for.

My problem is:
I want to check if username and email already exist or not in my database. Two separate functions for username and email. Another function is for storing data to database.

I don't know how to do this using asynchronous NodeJS pattern.

**User.js (mongoose Schema)**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    aiub_id: String,    
});
const Users = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports.addUser = function (user, callback) {
    user.save(callback);
}
module.exports.usernameExist = function (givenUsername, callback) {
    Users.find({ username: givenUsername }, callback);
}
module.exports.emailExist = function (givenEmail, callback) {
    Users.find({ username: givenEmail}, callback);
}
```

**index.js (route)**

```
route.post('/signup', function(req, res){
// GRAB USER INFO FROM HTML FORM
var newUser = new User({
    name : req.body.tfullName,
    username : req.body.tusername,
    password : req.body.tpassword,      
    email : req.body.temail,
    aiub_id : req.body.tuserID
});

// This block send 200 if username doesn't exist
User.usernameExist(newUser.username, function (err, result){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    if(result.length <= 0){
        res.send({status : 200 });
    }else{
        res.send({status : 100 });
    }
});

});
```

Please me help to solve this and please forgive if it sounds stupid.

Comment: You could run a single query using `$or` here. Then you don't need to worry about chaining callbacks and it's **much** less overhead and faster. Alternately, you could even just accept that a "duplicate error" returned amounts to the fact that one of the unique properties actually exists, then ask the user to try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Promise`s.

First I suggest you change your functions to return promises instead of taking callbacks:

```
function userExists(parameters) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    Users.find(parameters, (err, result) => {
      if(err){
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(result.length <= 0);
      }
    })
  );
}

module.exports.usernameExist = function (givenUsername) {
  return userExists({ username: givenUsername });
}

module.exports.emailExist = function (givenEmail) {
  return userExists({ email: givenEmail });
}
```

Then you wrap the promises returned from parallell calls to these functions in a `Promise.all`, which returns a new promise that resolves when all the wrapped promises get resolved, and then you do your stuff there:

```
Promise.all([
  User.usernameExist(newUser.username),
  User.emailExist(newUser.email)
]).then((results) => {
  // results[0] contains the result from User.usernameExist
  // results[1] contains the result from User.emailExist
});
```

If you do not want to change your functions in the `User` module, you can wrap the calls to those functions in `Promise`s in your index.js file instead.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. This is much readable. Let me check if it works for me or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just call one function in callback of other,

```
// Check if username doesn't exist
User.usernameExist(newUser.username, function (err, result){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    if(result.length <= 0){

        //check if email doesn't exist
        User.emailExist (newUser.email, function(err, result){
            if(result.length<=0){

                //save user
                User.addUser(newUser, (err, result)=>{
                     if(!err){
                         res.send({status : 200 });
                     }else{
                         res.send({status : 100 });
                     }
                })  
            }
        }
    }
});
```

People prefer promises to callback, to use promise you'll have to return a promise from your function. With promises code is easier to read so look into that.

Comment: Is it a valid asynchronous way? Sorry if it sounds stupid!

Comment: This doesn't leverage the power of asynchronicity.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Can you provide any alternate way for this problem?

Comment: @BigGuy Well according to  your problem, which is to first check for username, then email and then save the user, this is the way to do it, to call sequentially call funtions inside callback of previous functions. The better solution than this would be to use promises.

Comment: @anuragasaurus Yes I can

Comment: @MikaelLennholm I am curious. You can provide your code in a new answer.

Comment: @anuragasaurus Your description of the problem is not what the OP is asking for. *"Well according to your problem, which is to first check for username, then email and then save the user"* is not what OP wants, OP wants to check username and email **in parallell**, and then act when both results are available. Promises are indeed the solution.